# adjust brightness without reboot and in console?

Tags: 14.04, command-line, brightness

When I switch to a console by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F1</kbd>, the screen becomes darker than in <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F7</kbd>.

So I wonder how to adjust brightness in command line without reboot? My Ubuntu is 14.04 on Thinkpad T400 laptop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can adjust your brightness using the following command:

```
echo 7 | sudo tee /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness
```

The maximum value is available with:

```
$ cat /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/max_brightness
15
```

You may have to find the right device (here mine was `acpi_video0` but you can also have `intel_backlight`).

Comment: Thanks. How can you make the change of brightness take effect immediately?

Comment: @Tim That sounds like a new question :)

Comment: My post says "how to adjust brightness in command line without reboot? "

Comment: @Tim The command changes the brightness immediately. I guess that you need such command to be executed when you enter the console? Again I think this should be handled by some config/startup script. So could you please clarify? Thanks

Comment: Yes.   when I enter the console by ctrl-alt-F1, can `echo 7 | sudo tee /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness` change the brightness immediately?

Comment: How can I  find the right device?

Comment: you also said `intel_backlight`?

Comment: @Tim If you have `acpi_video0` prefer this one

Comment: You says to write to a text file, but what program changes the brightness and how?

Comment: It's a kernel interface (See https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/Debugging/Backlight#The_.2BAC8-sys.2BAC8-class.2BAC8-backlight_interface)

Answer (score 1):

```
xrandr -q | grep " connected"
```

Type that to find out the first block of text it spits out, which is your display.

Use that with the next command:

```
xrandr --output VGA1 --brightness 0.7
```

Go get it back to original brightness:

```
xrandr --output VGA1 --brightness 1
```

Comment: Thanks. (1) All the commands can't run in a text console. The error is `Can't open display`. They can run in graphical console (i.e. Ctrl-Alt-F7). (2) How can I check the current brightness in either a text or a graphicl console?